# JQuery set <select> index from the value of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I this select box :

```
<select id="owner_select">
  <option value="1">Hasan</option>
  <option value="5">aUser1</option>
  <option value="7">aUser2</option>
  <option value="8">aUser3</option>
</select>
```

I want to make an option selected, but I want it to be according the ID of the user in this list not the index, so I set the value of each option to the user ID.

How could I make one this options selected when I know just the ID, for example I got ID=5 so I want aUser1 to be selected.

Comment: @MattWilson there are plenty of dupes on this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('#owner_select').val(id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qWycT/

Answer (score 0):

```
function select( id ) {
    var select = $( '#owner_select' ),
        option = select.find( 'option' );

    option.each( function( index ) {
        if( $( this ).val() == id ) {
            $( this ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
        }
    });

    select = null, 
    option = null;
}
```